# Birt/Set Schema and Set Path

Tags: db2, database-schema, user-defined-functions, birt

I'm currently using a schema that will be changed to another schema in a couple of months. I do not not want to have to remove the SCHEMA_NAME multiple times from each report. All the reports so far have this format:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME1,
    SCHEMA_NAME.USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(COLUMN_NAME2),
    COLUMN_NAME3
FROM
SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

I want to remove the schema name from the query so it looks like this:

```
SET SCHEMA LROUIM;
SET PATH LROUIM;
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME1,
    USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(COLUMN_NAME2),
    COLUMN_NAME3
FROM
TABLE_NAME
```

I need the "SET SCHEMA" for the table name and "SET PATH" for the User Defined Function. This code works in Squirrel SQL, but if I insert this code into a Birt data set of type SQL SELECT QUERY, I get an error because of

```
SET SCHEMA LROUIM;
SET PATH LROUIM;
```

How do I implement SET SCHEMA and SET PATH in a SQL Select Query in Birt?

Answer (score 1):

I think BIRT uses a JDBC connexion, and you can modify the connection parameters by specifying a default schema.

Comment: You cannot issue multiple SQL commands in the OdaJDBCDataSet query. Only a SELECT statement is allowed. I don't know SquirrelSQL, but it should be possible to specify this somewhere in the connection properties.